# Jdev Crashes while doing migration

Tags: java, spring, jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

i have migrated Jdevtp4 to Jdev 11.1.2.3.0
Does anyone knows about this error..

```
Target URL -- http://localhost:7101/xxxxx/index.jsp
    <ADFContext> <getCurrent> Automatically initializing a DefaultContext for getCurrent.
    Caller should ensure that a DefaultContext is proper for this use.
    Memory leaks and/or unexpected behaviour may occur if the automatic initialization is performed improperly.
    This message may be avoided by performing initADFContext before using getCurrent().
    For more information please enable logging for oracle.adf.share.ADFContext at FINEST level.
    2013-01-24 14:38:52,027 ERROR [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' [com.cassiopae.cassiopae.container.servlets.CassiopaeFacesServlet] - <Some Other Exception>
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at javax.faces.application.Application.getResourceHandler(Application.java:287)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:503)
        at com.cassiopae.cassiopae.container.servlets.CassiopaeFacesServlet.service(CassiopaeFacesServlet.java:160)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.SharedLibraryFilter.doFilter(SharedLibraryFilter.java:135)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:69)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.ADSFilter.doFilter(ADSFilter.java:85)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:293)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:199)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.SharedLibraryFilter.doFilter(SharedLibraryFilter.java:135)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:69)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.ADSFilter.doFilter(ADSFilter.java:85)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:468)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:293)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:199)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at com.cj.trim.trimFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at com.cj.gzipflt.GzipFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at org.springframework.webflow.executor.jsf.FlowSystemCleanupFilter.doFilterInternal(FlowSystemCleanupFilter.java:41)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:442)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:139)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

Comment: I have worked with JDev and ADF in the past, I pity you at this point.

Comment: @KevinBowersox any help would be appriciated

Comment: I wish I could but ADF is wild, how long have you been using it?

Comment: just started 4 months ago

Comment: Run! That's all I can say just run away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at javax.faces.application.Application.getResourceHandler(Application.java:287)
```

This exception will be thrown when there's no proper [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html) been initialized. This can in turn happen when there's a mismatch in JSF API/impl version used. E.g. your webapp is running a JSF 2.0 API along with a JSF 1.2 impl.

You should investigate if the target container (Weblogic in your case) doesn't already ship with JSF out the box and depending on that investigate 2 options:

1. Utilize the JSF version provided by the container and make sure that your webapp does **not** have any JSF libraries in its `/WEB-INF/lib`.
2. Disable the JSF library provided by the container and make sure that your webapp provides the proper JSF API/impl versions in its `/WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: That's correct. You should ultimately end up with no duplicated libraries in runtime classpath. What's the problem? Did you expect other ways?

Comment: Nope i got it let me give try :)

Comment: i did same i removed all my jsf 1.2 jars and put 2.0 jar but same issue i am getting and also did vice versa that time i got new error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.application.ProjectStage  and this class belongs to jsf2.0 jar
at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
"

Comment: In other words, you haven't investigated at all if Weblogic is already providing JSF by itself? You should do that. If you have no idea what I mean, just remove all JSF JARs from your `/WEB-INF/lib` and deploy and let me know what happens (this is essentially point 1 of the answer).

Comment: Hi BalusC i removed all my JSF lib from my project classpath after build i am getting jsf classes compilation error..

Comment: then second option-- i used JSF 2.0 libraries then all the compilation error gone and build it after running server same exception i am getting..

Comment: finally able to remove this error it was about using old version of jsf.. Thanks Bal